# Are there free sitemap generators where I can choose the starting directory?

Tags: sitemap

I'm looking for a free sitemap generator for my own personal use - not for sending to google.

Some sites with excellent information might be badly designed - like a maze. For these sites, I'd like to create a sitemap that lists all the pages that interest me, and then visit the pages that I might have missed using the site's own links.

Most of the free generators have a page limit. But some sites - for example financial sites - would greatly exceed the limit.

So, for these sites, I would like to come down to maybe the second level, and ask for only "Pensions" or only "Investments", and ignore all the other financial products. These sites might have URLs such as:

```
www.financial_site.com/pensions
```

If such a tool is available, I would be grateful for any links.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A1 Sitemap Generator (not free but 30 days trial) allows setting root directory ending wih a slash, additional start crawl paths and "limit-to" + "exclude" filters for URL patterns (regular expressions can be used)

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: For the benefit of other people, I can say that this tool worked fine.